# Start workflow automatically

Tags: 2010, 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have a problem starting an automatic workflow when I create an item in the list.

explanation:

I have a list where a person creates a certain item in a list, and starts to save an automatic workflow and creates a list in another list and deletes the same item.

When you create this item in another list, it starts a workflow changing and saving the data in the list before. But this list does not start the automatic flow as I wanted.

[image]

Step 1 (list X): I create the item in the list X, and creates the item in the list Y, then delete the item in the list X.

Step 2 (list Y): Creates the item in the list Y, and starts the flow and then create the item in the list X and deletes the item in the list Y.

Step 3 (list X): This flow was to start to build as before, but is not running.

Note: In step 3 does not run the same as in step 1 not to have an infinite loop.

Comment: Which SharePoint version? Workflows have different behaviors depending on the version.

Comment: And is the system account involved in any of these actions?

Comment: I use sharepoint 2013 workflow with 2010. 

And do not use the system account.

Comment: @Renanfdo What are you trying to achieve with this kind of set up?

Comment: I have a list of beliefs that the person selects to have your opinion as anonymous, so you have to create the same anonymous item in another list, delete it and create an anonymous account called the item on that list, to use it one step at representation in the other list. Because there is no way to create an item in the same list that the flow acts ... So I use two lists, one for display and other support.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend inserting a pause before creating the item in the opposite list, doesn't need to be long, maybe just a minute.

SharePoint doesn't like you creating loops, so when if it detects one it will cut it off with an error similar to this

AutoStart Workflow: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Recursive workflows are not permitted

Although SharePoint usually allows the loop to run a handful of times before it throws up this error (in my experience on 2010)

But adding the small pause gets around this, though of course it will increase the amount of time to complete the task you want).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm testing, I put a 1 minute break but it will not always work, put 5 minutes and did not work.

Answer (score -1):

1. Make the user create the item in the Dummy List(List Y). Run the workflow which will create the item in List X (anonymous list).
2. Create another WF which will run on List X, it will delete the original post of the User from List Y.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing, read everything that is written in question and comments.

Comment: @Renanfdo So out of your 2 workflows which one is not getting fired.The one in point 1 or point 2?

Comment: Not working is step 3.