# Workflow history list always has "For more information, please read this article:" after every instance but workflows are fine

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, designer-workflow

I have SP2010 designer workflows running in SP2016 farm. They complete successfully but the workflow history records this line in the end by System Account: For more information, please read this article: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=323543&clcid=0x409

How can we fix this?
Regards,
Ash.

Comment: Do you have Post-completion Workflow Activities? The most common case for this is if you try to set approval status without having content approval enabled. Another issue: do you write into history after every step to examine whether a specific step fails without setting the workflow status to error? If not some more logging could help. And finally: what does the ULS Log say at this point? Are there more information visible in the SharePoint Logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I found the cause. On one of the problem lists the workflows were set to auto-start and kick off on item creation and modification.
It’s the recursive nature of the Workflows that's recording the message in workflow history. Found the following errors in ULS logs:

*WinWF Internal Error, terminating workflow Id# 3dd2a077-449a-418d-91d3-5cc2b5a709bc 
AutoStart Workflow: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Recursive workflows are not permitted.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowAutostartEventReceiver.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(SPSite superUserSite, SPWeb superUserWeb)*

Recursive workflows can overload SharePoint timer service and that’s why it records that message as an FYI. 
As suggested in the forums here we need to either modify the workflow design or add a pause action and see check:
[Start workflow automatically](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/97177/start-workflow-automatically) 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/81b405bd-cbdd-4a4d-8e8b-67e5134d3ccb/autostart-workflow-microsoftsharepointspexception-recursive-workflows-are-not-permitted?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious

One thing that's still puzzling me is why did we not see the same issue in SP2013 farm. This seems to have started only after migrating to SP2016.